# $A_f$ is not a local ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am searching for an example where $A_f$ is not a local ring, where $A$  is a commutative ring with unity, and $f$ is an element of $A$, and $A_f$ is the localized ring with multiplicative set $S=$ {$1,f,f^2,...$}

Comment: What commutative rings do you know? There might be an example there!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take any $A$ and $f=0$. Then $A_f = 0$ is not local.

Or take any non-local $A$ and $f=1$.

Comment: Ha! ha! ha! amazing, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Let $D$ be a DVR with $M$, its maximal ideal, generated by $t$ and consider $D[x,y]$.

If you localize by $t$ you obtain $D[x,y]_t=K[x,y]$ where $K$ is the fraction field of $D$.

Considering the maximal ideals $(x,y)$ and $(x-1,y-1)$ you obtain your counterexample.

Answer (score 2):

Try $A=K[X]$ and $f=X$. Then the non-zero prime ideals (which are also the maximal ideals) are given by all (monic) irreducible polynomials $\ne X$.

Answer (score 1):

Since the prime (resp. maximal) ideals of $A_f$ are the ideals $P_f$ where $P \subset A$ is a prime (resp. maximal) ideal not containing $f$, almost any ring and almost any element is an example: you have only to find some $f$ not contained in more than one maximal ideal.

This picture becomes much easier to grasp if you know the geometric interpretation of localization, in which the ring $A$ represents an affine variety (its set of prime ideals), the element $f$ represents an equation whose solution set is a subvariety (the primes not containing $f$), and the localization $A_f$ represents the complement of that subvariety.